# Regex number after certain number of numbers

Tags: regex, search, expression

I want to filter the percentage of a ChkDsk scan using Regex. The problem is that the output may differ from system to system because of the language, therefore my only option is to filter it by numbers.

An example output might look like the following:

```
Progress: 45836 of 509696 done; Stage:  8%; Total:  3%; ETA:   0:23:47 .  \r\n
Progress: 45836 of 509696 done; Stage:  8%; Total:  30%; ETA:   0:23:47 .  \r\n
Progress: 45836 of 509696 done; Stage:  8%; Total:  40%; ETA:   0:23:47 .  \r\n
Progress: 45836 of 509696 done; Stage:  8%; Total:  55%; ETA:   0:23:47 .  \r\n
Progress: 45836 of 509696 done; Stage:  8%; Total:  100%; ETA:   0:23:47 .  \r\n
```

My idea was to just grab the fourth number in the string, would that work?
I sadly don't know much about Regex and can't really find a fitting example on the web, so how might it be done the right way?

Comment: Which environment is this? And why not match on the word `Total: `?

Comment: @funkwurm The OP mentioned that the output may differ because of the language, so I guess "Total" might not always be called "Total" :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
:\s([^ ;]+);(?![^%\n]*%)
```

Try this.Grab the capture  or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eZ0yP4/35

Comment: Thanks a lot, but thats exactly the problem. I can't use the "total: " keyword, because it depends on the language :/

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
^(?:\D*\d+){3}\D*(\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aN3xB6/1

Here I'm starting at the beginning of the line, and capturing 3 sequences of non-numbers `\D` and numbers `\d` before capturing the number you want.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the ";" as a delimiter and take the third column (maybe more readable than complex regex) ...

```
$cat testdata | awk -F';' '{print $3}'
 Total: 3%
 Total: 30%
 Total: 40%
 Total: 55%
 Total: 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\s(\d+)%
```

Try this regexp! Group 1 will give you the last occurence of a number that is preceeded by a whitespace and followed by a % char. This is language independent. If you cannot be sure, that the two percentages are in this order in your message i don't think you'll have a general solution, as they both look the same - the language specific prefixes OR their order are what makes a difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

How to do it depends on the flavor/language you are using.  But if you use a simple regex to return sequences of digits:

```
\b[0-9]+\b
```

and just return the 4th instance, you should get your value.

In vbscript the code might look like:

```
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "\b[0-9]+\b"
If myRegExp.Test(SubjectString) Then
    Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
    ResultString = myMatches(3).Value
End If
```

This assumes that none of the section "names" include digits.